# Different CLGeocoder results between device and simulator. Why might this happen?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, clgeocoder

I am using the following code to get a Placemark (and coordinates) from a city name, both for mapping and current weather information.

When I run my application on a iPhone 15 Pro Max (in the simulator) I get correct location information using the string "London, GB" (as well any other city name I've given it.)

When I run it directly on an actual iPhone 15 Pro Max it does NOT return location information for "London, GB". (it does return proper results for other cities.)

Why might this be happening?
(function below)

I am running both the simulator and actual iPhone on the same wifi network.

```
    func getLocationFromCityName(cityName: String, citiesIndex: Int, gmtDiff: Int, completion: @escaping(_ coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(cityName) {
        let loc = $0?.first(where: { placemark in
            placemark.timeZone?.secondsFromGMT() == gmtDiff
        })
        if let loc {
            let city = loc.locality ?? loc.name
            let state = loc.administrativeArea
            let countryCode = loc.isoCountryCode
            if let city, let countryCode {
                let foundName = countryCode == "US" ? city + ", " + (state ?? "") : city + ", " + countryCode
                self.cities[citiesIndex].name = foundName
                self.changeNameInActiveCalendarAlertsOnCalendarEvents(oldCityName: cityName, cityName: foundName)
            }
        }
        completion($0?.first?.location?.coordinate, $1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the locales of both devices the same?

Comment: In addition to locale, you might also consider setting the device location (via the simulator menu) to be (roughly) the location of your device, and then try again.

Comment: This morning I checked all the suggestions given:
The locales of the simulator device is the same as that of the physical device.
I have also made sure that the locations of both devices are the same.

The behavior I was experiencing yesterday is no longer happening and the Placemark for "London, GB" is being found, as expected on the physical device. Same device, same wifi network... I do not know what might have changed.

How should I resolve this question? For hours yesterday there was a repeatable issue. I have made no deliberate changes and today the issue seems to be gone.